# MySql query keeps running after result

Tags: mysql

I have a Sql query with selects and joins. The query uses views to select the result set. I have an environment with multiple identical databases (except the users). The views are used to get access to specific records for the logged on users on the database and used to filter out deleted records (deleted records have a flag called deleted for reporting purposes).

When I run the query with user A on database X the query runs for a second and finishes without a problem. When I run the query with user B on database Y the query run for a second. Shows the result in the result view, but the query still runs in the background. After 15 minutes the query still runs.

I use Toad for this investigation, but the problem did occur in my .NET windows forms application, because user B complains about the results not showing up on the screen.

When I hover over the background query in Toad, the status is closing, but the query never finishes the closing status. Checked on the used tables, but they all seems fine. Can query the tables individually without any problems.

The query I used

```
SELECT po.*,    
      (SELECT stat.Datum
          FROM obprodstatus stat
         WHERE stat.OnbekendProductID = ob.OnbekendProductID)
          AS DatumStatus   
  FROM productomschrijving po
       INNER JOIN onbekendproduct ob
          ON ob.onbekendproductid = po.onbekendproductid       
  WHERE ob.afgesloten = 0
```

Comment: It does sound mysterious. But before you digg any deeper, why are you using a subquery? Try using this join instead: `SELECT m.*
s.datum AS "DatumStatus"
FROM productomschrijving m
JOIN onbekendproduct o ON o.onbekendproductid = m.onbekendproductid
JOIN obprodstatus s ON s.onbekendproductid = m.onbekendproductid
WHERE o.afgesloten = 0`. By using JOIN statement the DB engine can create an execution plan to predict which data it needs.

Comment: I stripped the query, the query is far more complex and because the query runs perfectly on database X I know the problem is not the query. I know some thing can be more efficient, but this is one of the efficient queries in the application :)

Comment: Using sub queries on large data sets can become problematic. Are the two databases identical? Do they contain the same amount of records? What about the db engine? Are they both the same? And the database/table collations?

Comment: databases are exactly the same because they are initially copies of each other and after that they are synchronized between each other (except for the database users itself because every database has their own users and access). Even more an other db engine would not explain why mysql cannot close the query when finished even more subqueries would not make any point in this case. I know it's not efficient, but the dataset used isn't very large. All records in the subtables counted would be a couple of thousand, that cannot be any problem I suppose.

Comment: The problem occurs in you .Net app. Does it also occur when you execute the same query in Toad?

Comment: a I mentioned I my starting post the problem occured for user B in the .NET application. User A has no problem in the .Net application. Reproducing the problem directly with the same users on the database in Toad gave me the above scenario of mysql not closing the query when finished for user B.

Comment: I'm guessing your query uses some user identification field(s) to get its resultset. What if you swap those field on a copy of the database? In example, if your query uses the user_id field swap those and check the result.

Comment: swap those? Yes, the view has a function to get access rights for the rows, but a select * on the view doesn't give me any problems.

Comment: I'm sorry you said you stripped the query, does the current user have impact on the result set?

Comment: yes, because on the view the user has access right to not all records (only right to records for his department)

Comment: SO you are running two different queries. Is the query of user B also problematic on database Y?

Comment: technically the query are different because of different userids furthermore they are completely the same. The query is not a problem on database Y